# Automated report with Google Analytics and Google Sheets not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-sheets

I need to pull the Pageviews, Users, Bounce Rate, and Conversion rate for a Goal. I'm using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on).

Following the steps I was able to build the report, and it works for Pageviews, Users and Bounce Rate. But I need the Conversion rate for a specific goal and it's not working.

I have this for the metrics field for the report:

```
ga:users
ga:bounceRate
ga:goalXXConversionRate
ga:pageviews
```

When I run the report, I get:

Unknown metric(s): ga:goalXXConversionRate For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.

Looking on there, it should work, but it's not. Hoping someone can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
ga:goalXXConversionRate
```

Should've been:

```
ga:goal1ConversionRate
```

Or whatever goals' conversion rate you want to return.

To get this, when you're on the GA property you want, go to Admin > Goals > And here look for the Goal you want, and use the ID number.